# The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am playing up with some code and have problem with my site master and Html tag

My application is based on asp.net MVC2 in c#

I want to use Html.RenderPartial to process my partial view in site.master.
How ever it doesn't work.

Any idea?

i include my code for you to see

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SportStore.WebUI.Views.Shared.Site" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
   <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
      <div class="title">Demo test</div>
    </div>
    <div id="categories">
          <% Html.RenderPartial("menu", product); %>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that your master inherits from `SportStore.WebUI.Views.Shared.Site` which is a custom class. Make sure that this custom class derives from [System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewmasterpage.aspx) so that the [Html](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewmasterpage.html.aspx) property is defined.

Comment: Darin, cannot i just include html property somehow?

Comment: @Pavel - in your base class you will need to instantiate an instance of `HtmlHelper` (or the derived generic type `HtmlHelper<TModel>`) and make this available as a property on the class. The easiest way to do this would be to derive your custom type from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage`

Comment: hh i did changed the master page to derive from System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage, <br> still i wanted to know how asi it was interesting. thnx works now well